# Filter unwanted INFO-Messages from Logger

Tags: java, soap, java.util.logging

I'm using `java.util.logging` to log in my Java application. I'm also using `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint` to publish a SOAP-interface.

Over the time I added more and more exceptions which all turn up at startup with a log-entry like this:

```
Jan 24, 2011 12:29:27 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getExceptionBeanClass
INFO: Dynamically creating exception bean Class de.wi08e.myhome.frontend.jaxws.NotLoggedInBean
```

I tried following filter to block them, but I'm not sure which class to get with `getLogger`:

```
/* Filter ExceptionBeanClass logs */
Logger loggerInfo = Logger.getLogger("javax.xml.ws.Endpoint");
loggerInfo.setFilter(new Filter() {

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord l) {
        System.out.println(l.getMessage());
        if (l.getMessage().startsWith("Dynamically creating exception bean Class"))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

});
```

Does anyone know how to find out which class creates this log-entries? Is there another way to filter out this nerving messages?

EDIT: I also tried `Logger.getLogger("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler")`, but it's still not working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just run the java program with the following flag: `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<mylogging.properties>` where mylogging.properties is a file with the following contents instead of doing it in code.

```
javax.enterprise.resource.webservices.jaxws.server.level = WARN
```

From http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/model/RuntimeModeler.java.html

```
  186       private static final Logger logger =
  187           Logger.getLogger(
  188               com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.Constants.LoggingDomain + ".server");
```

and from Constants

```
  public static final java.lang.String LoggingDomain = "javax.enterprise.resource.webservices.jaxws";
```

Comment: Does not work :-( "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler" seems to be the wrong classname, because the filtering-method is never called.

Comment: this won't call the filtering method that you defined, this just raise the minimum log level for that particular logger to WARN so that INFO messages are ignored.

are you sure you are running the program with "java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=<mylogging.properties> <classname>"?

Comment: Hey, you posted the same answer to your own question 5hrs later... :)

Comment: Oh no -- I'm sorry! I did some very quick copy and paste and it didn't work. But now I see, that you've bee right from the start - I should really stop dismissing answers this fast :-(

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Clement P answered this question right long before me; all thumbs-up should go to him!

I keep my answer here because it uses a slightly other way.

---

I've now solved it myself. In short, this is the solution:

```
Logger.getLogger("javax.enterprise.resource.webservices.jaxws.server").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

If anyone's interested, this is how I found it:

The method getExceptionBeanClass in [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler](http://fisheye5.cenqua.com/browse/~raw,r=1.18/jax-ws-sources/jaxws-ri/rt/src/com/sun/xml/ws/model/RuntimeModeler.java) is responsible for the messages. It uses a static `Logger` instanciated with the function

```
Logger.getLogger(com.sun.xml.ws.util.Constants.LoggingDomain + ".server");
```

Google-ing for `com.sun.xml.ws.util.Constants` leads [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.1.4/jaxws-rt-2.1.4-sources.jar!/com/sun/xml/ws/util/Constants.java?format=ok) where you can copy-and-past the `LoggingDomain` constant.

But keep in mind: This solution won't work on every JRE, because it depends on Sun's 'private' namespace and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The log entry seems to indicate that it's the com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler class which generates this log message. You should be able to filter it out by raisong the level for this logger.

Comment: Still not working: Logger loggerInfo = Logger.getLogger("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler");
loggerInfo.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
loggerInfo.setFilter(...);

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just create the missing class.
Actually, that's the standard procedure that I follow when creating webservices.

If you create this class (i.e. *de.wi08e.myhome.frontend.jaxws.NotLoggedInBean*),
then it will just use the existing class, without trying to create it at runtime.

Actually, you don't even have to create these classes yourself. You can generate them using the wsgen tool. The *wsgen.exe* is part of the java jdk. So, you can just run this from the commandline.

```
wsgen.exe -verbose -keep -cp . de.wi08e.myhome.frontend.WebService -d source
```

Next move the created files to the correct project source folder.