# Disable Log4j INFO-level logging when using FOP

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-fop

How can I remove the INFO level logging when generating PDF files using FOP?  I have this in my log4j.properties file:

log4j.logger.org.apache.fop = WARN

but I'm still getting these for each PDF file that is created:

[INFO] Using com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser as SAX2 Parser
[INFO] setting up fonts

Any ideas?  I looked @ this entry but it didn't answer my question:
[Filter unwanted INFO-Messages from Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781565/filter-unwanted-info-messages-from-logger)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the log entry is (a) from a class in org.apache.fop and (b) from log4j?

It may be a log output from one of FOP's sub packages like batik.

You can change your log4j appender layout to show the class of origin (e.g.,

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

), then you will know.