# Disable unwanted INFO-Messages from SOAP Logger

Tags: java, soap, java.util.logging

In question [Filter unwanted INFO-Messages from Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781565/filter-unwanted-info-messages-from-logger) it is proposed to disable unwanted SOAP INFO logging by raising the respective log level to WARNING like so:

```
// Disable SOAP-internal INFO logging
Logger.getLogger("javax.enterprise.resource.webservices.jaxws.server").setLevel(Level.WARNING)

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9999/ws/SoapControl?wsdl");
QName qname = new QName("http://example.ch/", "SoapControlImplService");

Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
SoapControl soapControl = service.getPort(SoapControl.class);  // Unwanted logging happens here
```

This usually works, but unfortunately not all the time, i.e. **the behavior is not deterministic**.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I found that `Logger.getLogger("javax.enterprise.resource.webservices.jaxws.server").getLevel()` returns null in cases where the unwanted logging happens.

Comment: Looks like you might be running into [garbage collection of loggers](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6949710)  Have you tried to pin the soap logger with a static final reference?  Otherwise you can add an entry into your logging.properties file to control the level on demand.

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly the problem. I could reproduce it running GC explicitly. Thank you! Keeping a reference to the logger solves the problem reliably for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be running into [garbage collection of loggers](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/i#browse/JDK-6949710).  Pin the soap logger with a static final reference or you can add an entry into your logging.properties file to control the level on demand.  Every time the logger is recreated the log level is read from the properties file.